# Generic deserialization

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace some old code with a more generic approach, therefore I tried using generics. Unfortunatley I didn't get it working so far. I have to load a hashmap of objects dynamically from a json String. But till now, I didn't get it working, since line 4

```
HashMap<String,c> hm = new HashMap<String,c>();
```

says 'Unknown class c'. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static HashMap<String,?> getEntries(Context context, Type t)
        {
            Class c = t.getClass();
            HashMap<String,c> hm = new HashMap<String,c>();
            try
            {
                File fl = new File(context.getCacheDir(),c.getClass().toString() + ".json");
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                fin.close();

                hm = new Gson().fromJson(sb.toString(), t);

            }catch(Exception i)
            {
            }
            return hm;
        }
```

Comment: This will not do what you expect it to do. A type argument has to be the name of a type. `c` is a variable.

Comment: `c.getClass().toString()` should btw evaluate to `"class java.lang.Class"` every time. c is already a `Class` object and `c.toString()` would print that already, it's class and every consequent class thereof will just print the same.

Comment: Good catch, @zapl. Lukas: `c.getSimpleName()` is probably more what you were going for with that bit.

Comment: Should probably not even use `Type` http://ideone.com/LFEN3b - there is no `.getSimpleName()` on `Type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer concisely, to be honest, because (constructively and objectively) you're missing some of the fundamental concepts of how generics work.

`c` is an instance of `Class` which is an `Object` like anything else. Generic type parameters must be *types*, not objects. If you want to place constraints on your `HashMap` type you will have to express those constraints in the form of generic type parameters. For example:

```
public static <T> HashMap<String,T> getEntries (Context context, Type type) {
    HashMap<String,T> hm = new HashMap<String,T>();
    ...
}
```

However, since there is no way to infer the type `T` from any of the parameters, the `Class` of `T` is not readily available within the method. A typical approach is to add some useful parameter that can also constrain the type, for example:

```
public static <T> HashMap<String,T> getEntries (Context context, Type type, Class<T> clazz) {
    HashMap<String,T> hm = new HashMap<String,T>();
    ...
}
```

With this, you can call like this:

```
HashMap<String,String> entries = getEntries(context, type, String.class);
```

And you can also use `clazz` as needed within the method.

Hopefully this is enough to get you inspired to move in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answered my question. I tried it in a similar way before, but I missed <T> after static which ended in a compiler error.

Comment: @Lukas Glad it helped; I may have conflated the purpose of your `Type` parameter with my `Class<T>` parameter in the example, but hopefully you get the idea. If you were referring to `java.lang.reflect.Type` there, unfortunately, there's really not much you can do with the `Type` interface; `Class` is usually what you want to stick with. As an aside, in some specific cases you might see arrays used for similar purposes, e.g. [`ArrayList.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])) (note parameterless version can only return `Object[]`).